# Can the GenServer `handle_continue` callback directly be invoked from another process?

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server

The `handle_continue` callback of a `GenServer` can be invoked by returning `{:noreply, state, {:continue, :foo}` from another callback inside the same `GenServer`.

If I have a small cascade of separate steps after the `GenServer.init` callback:

```
defmodule MyGenServer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(args \\ %{}) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, [])
  end
  
  @impl true
  def init(args) do
    {:ok, args, {:continue, :foo}}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_continue(:foo, state)
    case foo(state) do
      {:ok, state} ->
        {:noreply, state, {:continue, :bar}}

      {:error, :bar_not_set} ->
        {:noreply, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_continue(:bar, state)
    state = bar(state)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp foo(state = %{bar: _}) do
    {:ok, state}
  end
  defp foo(_state) do
    {:error, :bar_not_set}
  end

  defp bar(state) do
    # ...
    state
  end
end
```

the `handle_continue(:foo, state)` and `handle_continue(:bar, state)` callbacks are invoked in this order, if the `args` contained a `bar` key. If not, the `handle_continue(:bar, state)` callback is never invoked.

If I have started `MyGenServer` e.g. as part of a supervision tree:

```
...
children = [
  ...
  {MyGenServer, %{foo: "foo"}},
  ...
]
Supervisor.start_link(children, ...)
```

would it be possible to trigger the `MyGenServer.handle_continue(:bar, state)` callback from another process in the supervision tree?

It is more a question, about if invoking a `handle_continue` callback in any other way, than after a callback inside the same `GenServer`, is possible at all and not to find an alternative of executing the code in `handle_continue(:bar, state)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to invoke the callback directly, but you can always have:

```
def handle_cast(:invoke_the_continue, state) do 
    handle_continue(:bar, state)
end
```

and then call `GenServer.cast(your_server, :invoke_the_continue)` from outside your server.